# Jq - add a key/value to one JSON file if such key/value exists in another JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, if-statement, search, jq

There is one JSON file - **landline.json**

```
[
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Person": "John Doe",
        "Landline": false
    },
    {
        "City": "Los Angeles",
        "Person": "Steve Smith",
        "Landline": false
    }
]
```

And there is another JSON file - **mobile.json**

```
[
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Person": "John Doe",
        "Mobile": false
    },
    {
        "City": "Los Angeles",
        "Person": "Jenny Miller",
        "Mobile": false
    }
]
```

Question is how using **jq**'s filters and condition statement create a new file/array adding after the `"Landline": false` `"Mobile": false` for `John Doe`? So the resulting array should look like the following:

```
[
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Person": "John Doe",
        "Landline": false,
        "Mobile": false
    },
    {
        "City": "Los Angeles",
        "Person": "Steve Smith",
        "Landline": false
    }
]
```

So the algorithm should be following -  if in the `mobile.json` there is `"Person": "John Doe"` entry and in the same block there is `"Mobile": false` entry, then add `"Mobile": false` entry after `"Landline": false` for `"Person": "John Doe"` in `landline.json`.

Comment: Did you make some efforts on your own?

Comment: So, `Mobile` and `Landline` are the only keys differing between two files?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, Mobile and Landline are the only keys different. 

Probably also worth mentioning that in each file the value for "Person" is unique. In other words - you will have only one "Jon Doe" in San Franciso or in LA or in some other city.

Comment: Then you can also go with `jq -s 'add | group_by(.Person) | map(add | select(has("Landline") and (.Mobile | not)))' landline.json mobile.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a filter to get you started.  With the following in **merge.jq** and the other files you've specified

```
def key: [.Person, .City] ;
[
      reduce .[][] as $e ({}; setpath($e|key; getpath($e|key) + $e)) 
    | .[][]
    | select(.Landline != null)
]
```

The command

```
jq -Ms -f merge.jq landline.json mobile.json
```

produces

```
[
  {
    "City": "San Francisco",
    "Person": "John Doe",
    "Landline": false,
    "Mobile": false
  },
  {
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "Person": "Steve Smith",
    "Landline": false
  }
]
```

To understand what is going on here, observe how this filter

```
def key: [.Person, .City] ;
reduce .[][] as $e ({}; setpath($e|key; getpath($e|key) + $e))
```

constructs a temporary nested object whose keys are Person and City from the inputs

```
{
  "John Doe": {
    "San Francisco": {
      "City": "San Francisco",
      "Person": "John Doe",
      "Landline": false,
      "Mobile": false
    }
  },
  "Steve Smith": {
    "Los Angeles": {
      "City": "Los Angeles",
      "Person": "Steve Smith",
      "Landline": false
    }
  },
  "Jenny Miller": {
    "Los Angeles": {
      "City": "Los Angeles",
      "Person": "Jenny Miller",
      "Mobile": false
    }
  }
}
```

from this object iteration and select are used to convert back to the desired form keeping only objects with non-null Landline.

Comment: Perfect! You know what - the temporary array is probably a better solution.
Related question - can your solution expanded to include additional key? Like if there is an additional file car.json with `"car": false` additional key in it?

Comment: Answering my own comment above - yes, just requires running the above filter twice - one to get an intermediate result and then with car.json file to get the final result which will have `Mobile`, `Landline` and `Car` keys.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

For this type of problem, a "dictionary lookup" is easy to understand, and given jq's `INDEX` function, also easy to implement. Consider for example:

```
jq -n ' 
  def key: {City,Person};
  (input | INDEX(.[]; key) | map_values( {Mobile} ) ) as $mobile
  | input | map( . + $mobile[key|tostring] )
' mobile.json landline.json
```